# git checkout command does not work as expected

Tags: git, git-checkout

I have this:

```
git branch # I am on a feature branch "X"  
git fetch origin dev;
git checkout -b "${new_branch}" "origin/dev"
```

the problem is that the last command checks out a new branch with X as the base, instead of "origin/dev" as the base. Why would it do that? I was under the impression that `git checkout -b foo bar` would checkout a new branch called foo using bar as the "base" (please correct my terminology). Why wouldn't that work?

I am on git version: 2.17.1

perhaps I should use this instead:

```
git checkout -b "${new_branch}" --track origin/dev
```

?

**update**: what is likely happening is that origin/dev is getting updated with changes from the local feature branches. so the first command I am using does use origin/dev as the base, it's only that origin/dev is seeing updates from the feature branches because tracking was set up...

Comment: What, precisely (i.e., in terms of `git config --list` output for instance, or `git rev-parse ${new_branch}` result) do you mean by *with X as the base*?

Answer (score 2):

In your own answer you mentioned that:

> ```
> git checkout -b "${new_branch}" "origin/dev"
> ```
>
> means that the new branch will track origin/dev ...

This is correct, although it uses this rather badly overloaded word "track".  In the last few years, it seems to me that the Git documentation has been moving (slowly) away from this word, which is probably a good idea (although it persists in the `--track` and `--no-track` options!).

The more-appropriate / better / more-modern term is that the new branch will have `origin/dev` set as its *upstream*.  Each branch name can have one upstream setting.  This upstream is simply the name of a branch (e.g., `master`) or of a remote-tracking name (e.g., `origin/master`).  The presence of this setting, along with its actual value, affects how `git status` reports status, how `git merge` and `git rebase` behave when used with no additional arguments, and how `git pull` and `git push` behave with no additional arguments.<sup>1</sup>

Alternatively, a branch can have *no* upstream.  If a branch has *no* upstream, `git status` does not report a comparison of the branch to its nonexistent upstream, `git merge` and `git rebase` demand more arguments, and so on.  Note that the upstream setting, or lack thereof, is independent of the commit hash to which the branch-name points.

(See also [Make an existing Git branch track a remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/520650/1256452))

> What I did to fix it, was using --no-track, like so:
>
> ```
> git branch --no-track "${new_branch}" "remotes/origin/dev"
> git checkout "${new_branch}"
> ```

This will do the job, but you can also do it with:

```
git checkout --no-track -b "${new_branch}" origin/dev
```

---

<sup>1</sup>This is not meant to be a comprehensive list.  In particular `git branch -vv` also looks at the upstream setting, and `git for-each-ref` and `git rev-parse` have the ability to extract the upstream setting of a branch.  Moreover, parts of Git don't bother to verify whether the name to which the upstream is set, if it is set at all, is valid, but other parts of Git do; so there's quite a mishmash of possibilities here.

---

#### Background (with a lot of detail)

The precise default actions for both `git branch` and `git checkout` is a little bit complicated.  Git is trying to be helpful, but the result is just plain messy.

I think it helps to remember that a *branch name* acts as a pointer to *one particular commit*.  Git calls this the *tip commit* of the branch.  You may choose any existing commit in the entire repository, and attach a branch name there.  For instance, given a commit chain like this one:

```
...--E--F--G
            \
             H--I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
```

(with an inexplicable-as-yet kink in the drawing), we can go find the actual hash ID of commit `G` and attach a new branch name there now.  Let's say `G`'s actual hash ID starts with `491ab94`, so we run:

```
git branch marker 491ab94
```

The result looks like this:

```
...--E--F--G   <-- marker
            \
             H--I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Now there are two branches where there used to be just one.  The new branch, named `marker`, identifies commit `G`.  The existing `master` is unchanged: it continues to identify commit `J`.

#### Creating a new branch *requires* picking a commit

Whenever you create a new branch name, you must answer a question for Git: *Which existing commit should this branch name identify?*  Here, we picked `G` by its hash ID.  Since a hash ID is not a *name*, this ID *cannot* be set as the upstream for the new branch.

If you omit the hash ID in `git branch`, Git defaults to using `HEAD`:

```
git branch m2
```

Since `HEAD` is currently attached to `master`, this makes `m2` point to the same commit as `master`:

```
...--E--F--G   <-- marker
            \
             H--I--J   <-- master (HEAD), m2
```

In this case, the upstream of `m2` is left unset by default.

You can also create new branch names with `git checkout`.  The key difference between using `git branch` and `git checkout` is that `git checkout` *also* attaches `HEAD` to the new branch, moving to (checking out) a different commit than the previously-current commit if need be.  For instance:

```
git checkout -b m2
```

(instead of `git branch m2`) does not have to move at all, and does not move, but does re-attach `HEAD`, producing:

```
...--E--F--G   <-- marker
            \
             H--I--J   <-- master, m2 (HEAD)
```

Commit `J` is still the commit that is checked-out, but now `HEAD` is attached to the name `m2`.  As before, `m2` has no upstream.

#### *Sometimes*, picking a specific commit sets an upstream

As we just saw, if you let Git default to `HEAD`, Git *does not* set an upstream for the new branch.  Also, if you pick a specific commit *by its hash ID*, Git *does not* set an upstream.  But sometimes, if you pick a specific commit by *name*, Git *does* set an upstream.

So: when *does* Git set an upstream?  Well, consider the kinds of names we have for commits.  Some of them are our own branch names, like `master` and `m2` and `marker` above.  Some of them are tag names like `v1.2`.  Some are *remote-tracking* names like `origin/master` or `origin/develop`.  Which ones make the most sense as an upstream name?

If you said "the remote-tracking names", congratulations: you and Git think alike!  If not, well, perhaps that's why you're always at war with Git. :-)  Anyway, using a remote-tracking name as your starting-point tells Git: *Not only do I want you to create this new branch, I'd also like you to set this remote-tracking name as the branch's upstream.*

You can do the same thing *explicitly* using `--track`, and in this case, you can have Git set the upstream to one of your own branches.  For instance, to set the upstream of `develop` to `master` while creating `develop`, you can use:

```
git branch --track develop master
```

or:

```
git checkout --track -b develop master
```

If you dislike `--track` behavior (i.e., upstream-setting) at *all* times, you can either always add `--no-track` to your command, or configure Git *not* to automatically set remote-tracking names as upstreams, using:

```
git config branch.autoSetupMerge false
```

If you really *like* `--track` behavior a whole lot, and want it to happen even when using local branch names as starting points, you can configure Git to do this too:

```
git config branch.autoSetupMerge always
```

The `--track` and `--no-track` options, if you use them, override the configured default of `always` or `false` or `true`.  If you have not configured `branch.autoSetupMerge`, Git pretends you have it set to `true`, which means what we just outlined above:  *Default to `--track` if the name is a remote-tracking name.*

#### All of the above is purely meant to be convenient

You can always change, or remove, the upstream of any branch at any time, using `git branch --set-upstream-to` or `git branch --unset-upstream`.  So any fiddling you do with `--track` or `--no-track` or `branch.autoSetupMerge` is *meant* to be *convenient*.  Set this to whatever *you personally* find the most convenient.

#### One last twist: orphan branches

Above, I said that creating a new branch *requires* picking a starting commit.  This is true, but is almost a lie as well.  There's a corner case that occurs in every new, totally-empty repository.  Consider:

```
$ mkdir newrepo
$ cd newrepo
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
```

At this point, you have *no* commits, and `git branch` shows that you have *no branches* either.  And yet, `git status` tells you that you are on branch `master`.  How can this be?

```
$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

The answer is that you are on a branch name that does not exist.  Although this sounds self-contradictory, it's really just a special case in Git.  The *next* commit you make will be a *root* commit: a commit with no parent.  The act of creating this commit will produce a commit hash ID.  That commit hash ID will *create* the branch.

Hence, this branch that you are on (Git has saved the name in `HEAD`) does not exist, and you cannot set its upstream:

```
$ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master
fatal: branch 'master' does not exist
```

You must first create the branch, by committing.  Once the branch exists, *then* you can set its upstream.

This is true for a new, empty repository because of the fact that there are no commits yet.  But it's also true for any branch name you create with `git checkout --orphan`, which does this same trick: it writes the new branch *name* into `HEAD`, but does not actually *create the branch*.

What this boils down to is that the branch creation occurs by making a commit.  So for this particular corner case—an orphan branch that does not really exist yet, or the `master` branch in a new empty repository—you "choose" the commit to which the branch will point, not by looking at some existing commit, but by creating a *new* commit and, in the process, saying: *This new commit is my choice for where the branch name shall point.*  The new commit is a root commit (has no parent) and the branch now exists, and only now can Git set its upstream.

Thus, for orphan branches, you cannot set the upstream until the branch actually exists.

Comment: interesting, but why would the local upstream (remotes/origin/dev) branch ever have changes from other local branches if `git push` was never called?

Comment: In that case, it shouldn't: commits you make to a branch cause that branch name to point to the new commit, while remote-tracking names like `origin/dev` should be adjusted only if the *other Git* (at `origin`) has changed *its* `dev` to point to a different commit. If you have the commit and have never given it to `origin`, `origin`'s `dev` cannot point to that commit and your own `origin/dev` should therefore not point to that commit. (Whew!) On the other hand, if you *did* run `git push` with no arguments, and if your Git is configured to push your commits to `origin` and then [continued]

Comment: ... and then request that `origin`'s Git set *its* `dev` accordingly, and if they do so, your Git will adjust your `origin/dev` to match their `dev` that now points to that commit. Since that's entirely normal for Git, that's probably what actually happened: you, or someone else while you were not watching, pushed your commit to `origin`'s `dev`.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is what's happening is that this command:

```
git checkout -b "${new_branch}" "origin/dev"
```

means that the new branch will track origin/dev, which means origin/dev gets updated with local changes.

What I did to fix it, was using --no-track, like so:

```
git branch --no-track "${new_branch}" "remotes/origin/dev"
git checkout "${new_branch}"
```

I haven't completely verified that it works, but it seems to so far. Kind of a nightmare tho.

Answer (score 1):

I created this alias to perform this task:

```
git config --global alias.nb '!bash -c "git fetch --prune; git checkout -b $1 --no-track ${2-origin/dev}" -'
```

You'd run it using this command:

```
$ git nb <branch name> [<source commitish>]
```

It performs a full fetch with prune, and accepts two parameters, the first is the new branch name, the second is the source branch, but defaults to origin/dev if none is supplied.

Using `--track` would set you up to push your feature directly to origin/dev.

Also remember that branches are just pointers, so the command could be read as "Create a new branch pointer named `<branch name>` at the commit referenced by `origin/dev` without setting up remote tracking and check out the new branch"